# event date is only working on curent month in bic_calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "May", "June", "March", "April", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    var dayNames = [ "الاحد", "الاثنين", "ثلاثاء", "الاربعاء", "الخميس", "جمعه","سبت"];

    var events = [
        <?php 
            foreach($array_date as $date_of_event){
                echo '{
                    date: "'.$date_of_event.'" 
                } ,';
            }
        ?>
    ];

    $('#calendar').bic_calendar({

        //enable select
        enableSelect: true,
        //set day names
        dayNames: dayNames,
        //set month names
        monthNames: monthNames,
        //show dayNames
        showDays: true,
        //show month controller
        displayMonthController: true,
        //show year controller
        displayYearController: true,
        //change calendar to english format
        startWeekDay: 1,
        //set ajax call
        events: events,

    });

    $('.bic_calendar').removeClass('row');
    $('.table').addClass('table-bordered');
    $('.table.header').removeClass('table-bordered');
});
```

hello

i am tying to use bic_calendar from this [link](http://bichotll.github.io/bic_calendar/)

i used this cod to add the calendar to my website

but it is only working on the current month (meaning if the date of the event on 12/1/2017 it will not displaying on the calendar  )

i am trying a lot of times but i can not solve it so i hope to find any one to help

Comment: By looping through and echoing each element with a trailing `,`, it would end in a comma, no? Not sure your `events` array could possibly be valid.

Comment: you mean like this

Comment: while the loop if the date on decimber it diplaying successfully

Comment: do you try with static event array ?

Comment: what is the static event array